# Angular - How to create a middle layer to check anything before the controller run

Tags: angularjs

I'm new bee in angularjs development. I'm trying to create an application which has a filter before the controller called. For example, when user click the link to "userInformation" controller, the application will check if the user has logged in first. If logged in, the "userInfomation" will be called.
Thanks!

Comment: Just inject your service and use it in the controller before any function call. Something like `app,controller('YourController',function($scope, MyService){ $scope.linkClick = function(){ if(!MyService.IsLoggedIn) return; };})`

Answer (score 1):

You would typically add a property to the routing that determines the kind of authentication needed to access the route. In the $routeChangeStart event you would then check the permissions.

See this link for a complete sample http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/